# $g \circ f$ surjective and $f \circ g$ injective $\implies$ $f$ and $g$ are bijections

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f : A \to B$ and $g: B \to A$ be functions. Show that
$g \circ f$ surjective and $f \circ g$ injective $\implies$ $f$ and $g$ are bijective.

**My attempt:**

Suppose $g(x) = g(y)$. Then $f(g(x)) = f(g(y))$ so that $x = y$ by injectivity of $f \circ g$.

Now let $y \in A$. By sujectivity of $g \circ f$, there exists $x \in A$ such that $g(f(x)) = y$. But $z = f(x) \in A$ so we have $g(z) = y$ and hence $g$ is surjective.

I have that $g$ is bijective but I am stuck with proving that $f$ is bijective.

Comment: when $g(x)=g(y)$ how you are able to write $f(g(x))=f(g(y))$ without knowing that $f$ is Injective?

Comment: @EkaveeraKumarSharma If $a=b$, then $f(a)=f(b)$ for any function, injective or not.

Comment: @MathMajor  I believe you mean that that you still need to prove that $f$ is injective and $g$ surjective.

Comment: ya if $f$ is injective, then if $a=b$ $f(a)=f(b)$. but here a priori we do not know $f$ is injective

Comment: No, injectivity is not needed.  If $a=b$ but $f(a)\ne f(b)$ then $f$ would not be a function.

Comment: @EkaveeraKumarSharma I think you are confused about what "function" means

Comment: @EkaveeraKumarSharma A function can only map to one output for every input ...

Comment: @MathMajor Did you make a mistake in your last paragraph.  Don't you mean that you are stuck on showing that $f$ is injective and $g$ is surjective?

Comment: Yeah fine i got my error

Comment: @TimRaczkowski Fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since $gof$ is Surjective for every $y \in A$ $\exists$ $x \in A$ such that

$$gof(x)=y$$ $\implies$

$$g(f(x))=y \tag{1}$$

But since we know that $g$ is surjective, for every $y \in A$ $\exists$ $z \in B$ such that

$$g(z)=y \tag{2}$$ Using $(2)$ in $(1)$ we get

$$g(f(x))=g(z)$$ But since $g$ is Injective

$$f(x)=z$$ which proves $f$ is Surjective.

Comment: How would i sh ow that $f$ is injective?

Comment: working on it please give me some time

Comment: Let $g(x)=a$ and $g(y)=b$. Assuming $fog(x)=fog(y)$, since $fog$ is Injective it means $x=y$ $\implies$ $g(x)=g(y)$ i.e., $a=b$. But my assumption is $f(g(x))=f(g(y))$ i.e., $f(a)=f(b)$. Finally if we assume $f(a)=f(b)$ we ended up with $a=b$. so $f$ is Injective.

Comment: @MathMajor: Do you see *why* showing that $f(g(x))=f(g(y))\implies g(x)=g(y)$ is enough to prove that $f$ is injective? There is a key point that Ekaveera neglected to mention.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: You have that $g$ is bijective. Use the following facts about bijective, injective and surjective functions:

- Every bijective function $h: C \to D$ has an inverse $h^{-1}: D \to C$ so that $h \circ h^{-1} = id_D$ and $h^{-1} \circ h = id_C$.
- If you compose a bijective function with an injective function (in either order), you get an injective function.
- If you compose a bijective function with a surjective function (in either order), you get a surjective function.

Comment: I made a mistake in my question, I do not yet know if $f$ or $g$ are bijective.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your proof that $g$ is injective and surjective... ?

Comment: You said that I have $g$ and $g \circ f$ as bijective, why?

Comment: You know that $g\circ f$ is bijective and you've shown that $g$ is bijective.  Let $h=g\circ f$, then $f=g^{-1}\circ h$ is a composition of bijective functions.

Comment: I'm not sure how Tim managed to convince you that you hadn't proved that $g$ was bijective. What you wrote was literally a proof that $g$ is injective followed by a proof that $g$ is surjective.

Comment: It is my fault. There is a typo in my question statement. I only know that $ g \circ f$ is surjective.

Comment: Okay, I understand, but there really was a typo, $g \circ f$ is not bijective, only surjective.

Comment: Even efter editing, still  your proof that $g$ is bijective is correct

Comment: Oh. The title should be edited.

Comment: Sorry, my apologies.

Comment: And as Ekaveera Kumar Sharma said, your proof that $g$ is bijective remains correct. But since you don't know, a priori, that $g \circ f$ is bijective, my solution doesn't work.

Comment: @MathMajor I've edited my hint accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how this helps

Comment: It's just a hint. Take some time to think about it.

Comment: Would you be able to provide the full solution?

Comment: Maybe tomorrow.

Comment: .... if no one else has already done so.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following facts to do your heavy lifting:

> **Proposition A.** Given functions $g : Z \leftarrow Y$ and $f : Y \leftarrow X$...
>
> 1. If $g \circ f$ is surjective, then so too is $g$.
> 2. If $g \circ f$ is injective, then so too is $f$.

The proof is left as an exercise for the reader.

> **Proposition B.** Given a function $f : Y \leftarrow X$ and a pair of isomorphisms $$\beta : Z \leftarrow Y \qquad \alpha : X \leftarrow W,$$ we have:
>
> 1. The following are equivalent:
>
>    $f$ is surjective, $\qquad$ $\beta \circ f$ is surjective, $\qquad$
>      $f \circ \alpha$ is surjective
> 2. The following are equivalent:
>
>    $f$ is injective, $\qquad$ $\beta \circ f$ is injective, $\qquad$ $f \circ \alpha$ is injective

Once again, the proof is left as an exercise for the reader.

Let us now turn our attention to your problem.

> **Claim.** Given functions $q : A \leftarrow B$ and $p : B \leftarrow A$, if $q \circ p$ is surjective and $p \circ q$ is
>   injective, then $q$ and $p$ are isomorphisms.

*Proof.* From A1 and the surjectivity of $q \circ p$, we deduce that $q$ is surjective. From A2 and the injectivity of $p \circ q$, we deduce that $q$ is injective. Hence $q$ is an isomorphism.

From B1 and the surjectivity of $q \circ p$, we deduce that $p$ is surjective. From B2 and the injectivity of $q \circ p$, we deduce that $p$ is injective. Hence $q$ is an isomorphism. QED

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would you put the notational expression "$g:Z\leftarrow Y$" in words?

Comment: @CameronBuie I tend to verbalize it "$g$ mapping into $Z$ from $Y$." For example I would read "Let $g$ denote a function $Z \leftarrow Y$" as "Let $g$ denote a function mapping into $Z$ from $Y$."

Comment: My thanks! I am unused to seeing the arrow go to the left, so I was curious.

Comment: @CameronBuie, no worries. This is a very uncommon convention, of course, but perhaps the benefits outweigh the costs.